# mysql-server error after upgrading to 22.04

Tags: upgrade, mysql

Recently I upgraded my Ubuntu server to 22.04, but in apt I get error:

```
ERROR: Unable to start MySQL server:
mysqld: error while loading shared libraries: libevent_core-2.1.so.7: failed to map segment from shared object
Please take a look at https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/MySQL/FAQ for tips on fixing common upgrade issues.
Once the problem is resolved, run apt-get --fix-broken install to retry.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-8.0; however:
  Package mysql-server-8.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What does this mean? "`error while loading shared libraries: libevent_core-2.1.so.7: failed to map segment from shared object`"? I tried to remove and reinstall libevent_core, but the problem persist.